# Set sensitivity labels for emails in Python using SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp

The following is the SMTP client I am using for sending emails. I want to set a Sensitivity label.
I tried adding it to the msg like:
`msg['Sensitivity'] = '2'` or `msg['Sensitivity'] = 'Confidential'`.

But neither worked. Any help is appreciated.

```py
    msg = MIMEText(content, style)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ','.join('%s@company.com' % x for x in to_list)
   

    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP(LI_SMTP)
        s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example code for sending mail --
import smtplib, SSL

```
port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "my@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "your@gmail.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter:")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am able to send the email. I want to add the sensitivity information as well. Unable to add the "sensitivity" information.